# How to find the difference between two queries returning count value in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

````
```    
Query 1: db.TestItems.find({
    $and: [{
    $or: [
    {"data.questions.stimulus" : /\\\\\w+/},
    {"data.questions.options.label" : /\\\\\w+/},
    {"data.questions.validation.validResponse.value" : /\\\\\w+/},
    {"data.questions.validation.altResponses.value": /\\\\\w+/},
    {"data.questions.hints.label": /\\\\\w+/}`enter code here`
    ]}, {"createdBy._id": ObjectId("5e9dac4699a7bb0007e33460")}]
    }).count();

    Query 2: db.TestItems.find({"createdBy._id": ObjectId("5e9dac4699a7bb0007e33460")}).count();```
````

I want to find the difference between the Query 2 and Query 1?

Answer (score 0):

You could use and aggregation with [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html#facet-aggregation) to run both queries and then use `$subtract`, like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {$facet:{
             total:[
                    {$match: {"createdBy._id": ObjectId("5e9dac4699a7bb0007e33460")}},
                    {$count: "count"}
             ],
             constrained:[
                    {$match:{
                       "createdBy._id": ObjectId("5e9dac4699a7bb0007e33460"),
                       $or:[
                            {"data.questions.stimulus" : /\\\\\w+/},
                            {"data.questions.options.label" : /\\\\\w+/},
                            {"data.questions.validation.validResponse.value" : /\\\\\w+/},
                            {"data.questions.validation.altResponses.value": /\\\\\w+/},
                            {"data.questions.hints.label": /\\\\\w+/}
                       ]
                    }},
                    {$count: "count"}
             ]
   }},
   {$addFields: {
                 total:{$arrayElemAt:["$total",0]},
                 constrained:{$arrayElemAt:["$constrained",0]}
   }},
   {$addFields:{
       difference:{
           $subtract:[
                      "$total.count",
                      "$constrained.count"
                     ]
       }
   }}
])
```

Or you could use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#group-aggregation) like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {"createdBy._id": ObjectId("5e9dac4699a7bb0007e33460")}},
    {$group: {
       _id:"$createdBy._id",
       total:{$sum:1},
       constrained:{
          $sum:{
            $cond:{
                 if:{
                     $or:[
                          {$regexMatch:{
                                        input:"$data.questions.stimulus", 
                                        regex: /\\\\\w+/}},
                          {$regexMatch:{
                                        input:"$data.questions.options.label", 
                                        regex: /\\\\\w+/}},
                          {$regexMatch:{
                                        input:"$data.questions.validation.validResponse.value",
                                        regex:/\\\\\w+/}},
                          {$regexMatch:{
                                        input:"$data.questions.validation.altResponses.value",
                                        regex: /\\\\\w+/}},
                          {$regexMatch:{
                                        input:"$data.questions.hints.label",
                                        regex: /\\\\\w+/}}
                     ]
                 },
                 then:1,
                 else:0
            }
          }
        }
    }},
    {$addFields:{difference:{$subtract:["$total","$constrained"]}}}
])
```

Comment: Why if condition here @joe and these one is giving error in $regexMatch

2020-04-22T13:55:49.576+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$regexMatch'",
 "code" : 168,
 "codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator",
 "operationTime" : Timestamp(1587543944, 1),
 "$clusterTime" : {
  "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1587543945, 1),
  "signature" : {
   "hash" : BinData(0,"QmiPRUA/ZGPud/hD81+IQrFHQyo="),
   "keyId" : NumberLong("6760588740801855515")
  }
 }
} : aggregate failed :

Comment: $regexMatch is new in MongoDB 4.2.  If you are using an older version, you'll need to use $facet so you can use the regular expressions in a $match stage.

Comment: `total` is incremented by 1 for every document, giving you a total count, while `constrained` is only incremented if one of the regexMatch returns true.  The [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html#cond-aggregation) returns 0 if none of them match.

Comment: Can you help me with facet, I'm new to mongo?

Comment: Those regular expressions appear to be looking for 4 backslash characters followed by a letter, was that what you intended?

Comment: Yes I am looking for latex values

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, it's just hard to index or optimize for